# Java Joda-Time DateTime How to Create a Date from a Julian date

Tags: java, datetime, julian-date

If I execute this statement using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
System.out.println(new DateTime(1387947600*1000L));
```

It prints out this date:

```
2013-12-24T23:00:00.000-06:00
```

What I am trying to create is this exact date but all I have is Julian date format 13359 in EST time zone.  What I have tried is appending "20" to my julian date, giving me the String "2013359".  Then I use the code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyDDD");   
DateTime test1 = formatter.parseDateTime(d2);
```

When I print out test1, it gives me:

```
2013-12-25T00:00:00.000-06:00
```

If I convert test1 to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time using

```
DateTime test2 = test1.withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
```

And then print out test2, I get:

```
2013-12-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

This is not what I am looking for.  How can I go from

```
"13359" in EST zone
```

to

```
2013-12-24T23:00:00.000-06:00
```

Anybody have any idea?  I have spent weeks on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, what you actually want is 11pm the day before the date you actually have. Note: Day 359 for a non-leap year (2013) is December 25.

Try this:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class JulianDateTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String julianDateString = "13359";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyDDD");
    DateTime lcd = formatter.parseDateTime("20" + julianDateString);
    DateTime lcdWeWant = lcd.minusDays(1).hourOfDay().withMaximumValue();

    System.out.println("Input: " + julianDateString + ", formats as '" + lcd.toString());
    System.out.println("The date we want is '" + lcdWeWant.toString() + "'");
    System.out.println("The \"date\" we REALLY want is " + lcdWeWant.getMillis());

  }

}
```

Which outputs:

```
Input: 13359, formats as '2013-12-25T00:00:00.000-06:00
The date we want is '2013-12-24T23:00:00.000-06:00'
The "date" we REALLY want is 1387947600000
```

See [here for Julian Day calendar from Nasa](http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/browse/calendar.html)

Comment: @J Steven Perry, thanks for your help.  Let me specify a couple more things. What I ultimately need is the "posix time" of 12/25/2013 EST.  I am told that the number I am looking for is 1387947600 (which is essentially 2013-12-24T23:00:00.000-06:00).getMillis()/1000).  What I have is "13359" in EST.  What I need to get to is 2013-12-24T23:00:00.000-06:00 so that when I use the getMillis() method and then divide by 1000, I get an output of 1387947600.  Does this clarify a little bit?

Comment: I think I understand what you need now. Take a look and see if this code gives you the desired output. I should have read your post more clearly. You need the timezone offset in the solution, so the millis have the correct value. Let me know if this works (and don't forget to accept if you like it! :))

Comment: @J Steven Perry Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I am not even quite sure what     lcd.minusDays(1).hourOfDay().withMaximumValue() is doing, but it works!  I will plug it in to my program, and hopefully it will work just as well for other julian dates.  Thank you again.